# Why this switch isn't giving any output?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I've been trying a while to solve this out for my schoolproject, but somehow i can't get this done.

What i' trying to do is to get a temperature from user and by using switch to give a feedback. So fr nothing comes out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Lämpötilan arvio</h1>
<p>Syötä kesäpäivän lämpötila ja klikkaa arvioi.</p>
<form>

<label for="temperature">Lämpötila:</label>
<input type="text" id="temperature"><br>

<input type="button" value="Arvioi" onclick="evaluate()"><br>
<p id="result">Ulkona on</p>
</form>
<script>
  function evaluate(){
  var temperature = document.getElementById("temperature").value;
  var result = ""
  switch (temperature) {
  case (Number(temperature) < 11):
    result = "KYLMÄÄ";
    break;
  case (Number(temperature) < 16):
    result = "KOLEAA";
    break;
  case (Number(temperature) < 21):
    result = "MELKO LÄMMINTÄ";
    break;
  case (Number(temperature) < 26):
    result = "LÄMMINTÄ";
    break;
  case (Number(temperature) < 31):
    result = "HELLETTÄ";
}
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Reading [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) is always useful. "_A case clause [is] used to match against expression_"

Comment: Because `temperature` doesn't match any of the `case` expressions (which all are either `true` or `false`). See MDN's documentation for [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch).

Comment: You are using the wrong tool; use `if-else` statements

Comment: Also, you cannot name a function `evaluate` because there's an already function with the same name in js.

Comment: @MohamedSayed Only in `document`, that won't conflict with global variables.

Comment: What you actually need, is a rating function. When resolving such tasks, it's always worth of considering whether it's possible to create some reusable generic snippets instead of a case-specific code. Take a look at [this jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/9zuk352c/) of a generic rating function.